# How can I find out the 'Klein-Gordon' equation by using Path Integral techniq?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, klein-gordon-equation

I get the following relation from eqn. (6.52) in Sakurai(2nd edition)
$$\Psi +\Delta t \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}+\Delta t^2\frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial t^2}+...=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar i \Delta t}}\left( 1-\frac{iV\Delta t}{\hbar}-{V^2\Delta t^2}{2\hbar^2}+...\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\xi exp\left(\frac{im\xi^2}{2\hbar \Delta t} \right)\left[ \Psi+\xi\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\xi^2}{2!}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}+...\right]$$
Where I let $\Psi=<x,t|x_1,t_1>$.
Now I want the Klein-Gordon equation by putting $$m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$

Where $\beta = \frac{v}{c}=\frac{\xi}{c\Delta t}$.
Could I get the Klein-Gordon equation by this modification? Do I need any more modification?

I don't want [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226161382_Klein-Gordon_equation_from_the_path_integral_formalism/link/564468ba08aef646e6caa22a/download) process.